# How to easy commit Android Studio

Tags: java, android, git, github

ive recently started with android studio and im making easy programs, but i need to perform several commits during my code development

Ive already installed GIT, checked out if it connects properly with GIT server and my account (Everything ok)

I created a repository from **VCS -> Import into version control -> Share project on Github** (Everything ok)

But when i want to commit all my project (with all the subfolders) for the first time, i select the desired folder but when it commits and pushs, only two txt files appears on my github account **("RunConfigurations.xml" and "vcs.xml")**

Ive always used Github Desktop for developing in C++, Java, Haskell, etc. 
But i cant use it here since i dont know how

Is there a quick and easy way to do commits in android studio, using GIT or Github desktop?

Thanks

Comment: In project view mode, right click on root folder -> Git -> Add, then Git -> Commit

Answer (score 6):

You can follow below 10 steps to Push your data,

**Step1:**

[image: Goto VCS >> Enable Version Control]

**Step 2:**

[image: Choose Git]

**Step 3:**

[image: Right Click on app >> Git >> Add]

**Step 4:**

[image: Then VCS >> Git >> Push]

**Orr**

**Step 4:**
[image: Directly click on these buttons]

**Step 5:**

[image: Check these options]

**Step 6:**

[image: Click on Commit and Push]

**Step 7:**

[image: Click on Define Remote]

**Step 8:**

[image: Enter path to your Repository here]

**Step 9:**

[image: Click on Push]

**Step 10:**

[image: Data Pushed Successfully]