# How to commit changes to existing repository from Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I have already share my android project on Github. But I had to make some changes later on, now how do I commit these changes to the same existing repository ?

Comment: You can follow simple steps provided in this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52565212/how-to-easy-commit-android-studio/52565525#52565525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look open the tab on bottom android studio named Version Control

then commit changelist by right click like below picture and click Commit File...

[image]

Then Commit And Push your changelist to your repository

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is safer to make a branch and make your changes then push to the master.
[Click on bottom of the right corner(master)->New branch->Branch name->Create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTI2e.jpg)

Next VCS->Git->Commit and give commit.
Then you can Push the branch to the gitHub
VCS->Git->Push